# How to fetch the last record from the table in mysql without order by

Tags: mysql

How to fetch the last record from the table without using orderby .?

Comment: The concept "last" **requires** some idea of "order". Either you mean ordered implicitly by date & time added, ordered implicitly by physical position in storage (which is unpredictable) or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do it but this will help

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [id] > (SELECT MAX([id]) - 1 FROM [MyTable])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in sql

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

`select * from table where Id=LAST_INSERT_ID()`

This does however require that you know the last table that was affected and that the row has a unique id.

You can aslo use this approach to get the last `Id` in your table:

`select max(Id) as LastInsertdId from table;`

**Note**

Don't use `*` in your select, always specify the columns!

Comment: why not to use `*` ? is it better to specify the columns?